# How to get url from RouteTable.Routes collection by key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

How to get url from RouteTable.Routes collection by key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
RouteBase route = routes["key"];
```

*RouteTable.Routes["key"]*

Answer (score 5):

untested, but seen here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680171.aspx)

```
RouteTable.Items[ "myRouteName" ]
```

to get the Url i would try this

```
( (Route) RouteTable.Items[ "myRouteName" ] ).Url
```

Attention: The items collection can return null if a route with the specified name
don't exists.